Issues with javascript dates /times on server vs local browser (react)
I have a set of code running that checks two dates. If those two dates/times occurred on the same day, one course of action is taken. If they are not, a different set of components are shown. The code initially renders server side and we noticed that there were cases where the server side did not match the client side and this led to a refresh of those components.
We noticed that if one date/time was after 7pm, the date-fns function isSameDay returned false when run on the server despite the two dates being on the same day. This did not happen on the client. Comparing those dates with the .getDate() function on the javascript object also showed different days for the same case.
I output the GMT string, the ISO string, and the date, month and year of a blank date object (current date/time) as well as the two date/time strings referred to as Date 2 and Date 1 using the code below ...
    <div>
      <div>{new Date().toGMTString()}</div>
      <Divider />
      <div>{new Date(Date2).toGMTString()}</div>
      <Divider />
      <div>{Date1.toGMTString()}</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>{new Date().toISOString()}</div>
      <Divider />
      <div>{Date2.toISOString()}</div>
      <Divider />
      <div>{Date1.toISOString()}</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>{`${new Date().getDate()}-${new Date().getMonth()}-${new Date().getFullYear()}`}</div>
      <Divider />
      <div>{`${Date2.getDate()}-${Date2.getMonth()}-${Date2.getFullYear()}`}</div>
      <Divider />
      <div>{`${Date1.getDate()}-${Date1.getMonth()}-${Date1.getFullYear()}`}</div>
    </div>


The strings used to create Date 1 and Date 2 are as follows :
Date1 - "2024-07-18T15:05:02.842Z"
Date2 - "2024-07-19T00:10:00Z"
Server Side Results



Item
Now
Date 2
Date 1




GMT
Tue, 05 Nov 2024 16:33:12 GMT
Fri, 19 Jul 2024 00:10:00 GMT
Thu, 18 Jul 2024 15:05:02 GMT


ISO
2024-11-05T16:33:12.035Z
2024-07-19T00:10:00.000Z
2024-07-18T15:05:02.842Z


Day,month,year
5-10-2024
19-6-2024
18-6-2024



Client Side Results



Item
Now
Date 2
Date 1




GMT
Tue, 05 Nov 2024 16:33:32 GMT
Fri, 19 Jul 2024 00:10:00 GMT
Thu, 18 Jul 2024 15:05:02 GMT


ISO
2024-11-05T16:33:32.820Z
2024-07-19T00:10:00.000Z
2024-07-18T15:05:02.842Z


Day,month,year
5-10-2024
18-6-2024
18-6-2024



The reason for the two interpretations is likely a timezone issue with my local timezone being 5 hours behind UTC.
The issue is that when Date2 was selected, 7pm on the 18th was selected and i'm not sure why it was stored improperly.
How do I address this? Can I convert "2024-07-19T00:10:00Z" to my local time zone?

What's the timezone in your browser and what's the timezone on the server?

I think that is the issue. My timezone is US Central. I am not sure the timezone of the server. It's a third party application and it looks like I selected a central time and it was stored improperly.

Are all visitors of your app/website in one specific timezone?

No. Unfortunately.

Do you want UTC dates? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate

@jabaa No. The UTC date for the original timestamp is the 19th.

The alternativea are to either send the local timezone to the server before it renders the website or to locally patch the values. Both options require some complex logic and AFAIK, there is no built-in or library solution for this. Here are some articles https://blog.6nok.org/server-side-rendering-local-dates-without-fouc/, https://www.jacobparis.com/content/remix-ssr-dates, https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/i9fndq/ssr_timezones/?rdt=51413

What does "same day" mean? If you want the same local day, then just send a string in say YYYY-MM-DD format using something like new Date().toLocaleString('en-ca').slice(0,10), then just compare strings or Dates at the server. Using UTC methods means you're using "same day" in a UTC context, which is likely not what you want.

You can use the UTC versions of the functions:

Date.prototype.getUTCDate()
Date.prototype.getUTCMonth()
Date.prototype.getUTCFullYear()

in the browser to get the same values
<div>
  <div>{new Date().toGMTString()}</div>
  <Divider />
  <div>{new Date(Date2).toGMTString()}</div>
  <Divider />
  <div>{Date1.toGMTString()}</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>{new Date().toISOString()}</div>
  <Divider />
  <div>{Date2.toISOString()}</div>
  <Divider />
  <div>{Date1.toISOString()}</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>{`${new Date().getUTCDate()}-${new Date().getUTCMonth()}-${new Date().getUTCFullYear()}`}</div>
  <Divider />
  <div>{`${Date2.getUTCDate()}-${Date2.getUTCMonth()}-${Date2.getUTCFullYear()}`}</div>
  <Divider />
  <div>{`${Date1.getUTCDate()}-${Date1.getUTCMonth()}-${Date1.getUTCFullYear()}`}</div>
</div>

Server Side Results



Item
Now
Date 2
Date 1




GMT
Tue, 05 Nov 2024 16:33:12 GMT
Fri, 19 Jul 2024 00:10:00 GMT
Thu, 18 Jul 2024 15:05:02 GMT


ISO
2024-11-05T16:33:12.035Z
2024-07-19T00:10:00.000Z
2024-07-18T15:05:02.842Z


Day,month,year
5-10-2024
19-6-2024
18-6-2024



Client Side Results



Item
Now
Date 2
Date 1




GMT
Tue, 05 Nov 2024 16:33:32 GMT
Fri, 19 Jul 2024 00:10:00 GMT
Thu, 18 Jul 2024 15:05:02 GMT


ISO
2024-11-05T16:33:32.820Z
2024-07-19T00:10:00.000Z
2024-07-18T15:05:02.842Z


Day,month,year
5-10-2024
19-6-2024
18-6-2024




Unfortunately, the UTCDate is the 19th for the string given. That is why this is so confusing.
